# Python! Finding pairs depending on maximum distance from words in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, range

I am writing a program that analyzes words in text files. I have been able to parse all words in the text file and append them to a list after grueling code. I have now hit a bump in this code. I am now supposed to find the pairs of words(for every word) that does not exceed the maximum distance in indices.
Here is the input and the list of strings I was able to get:

```
dist_max = int(input('Enter the maximum distance between words ==> '))

list_for_pairs = ['station', 'apple', 'chivalry', 'mansion', 'bear', \
                  'website', 'vest', 'amazing', 'mansion', 'apple', 'card', \
                  'station', 'card', 'book', 'same', 'tree', 'honor', \
                  'leaf', 'trace', 'tractor', 'bucket', 'bread', 'pears', 'book', \
                  'tractor', 'mouse', 'mansion', 'scratch', 'matter', 'trace']
```

In this case, the maximum distance should be 2, and for example, for the word 'amazing' in the list, the pairs that 'amazing' should pair up with would be 'website', 'vest', 'mansion', and 'apple'. This is because the maximum distance is 2, and all words are within that range in the list.
This is also an example output.

The pairs must be alphabetically ordered, with only the first and last 5 appearing, but it should say how many there are total.
Finally my code:

```
pair_list = []
for i in range(len(list_for_pairs)+1):
    range_pos = int(range(0, dist_max)) # This is the range for the maximum distance
    # between words in the positive (+) direction
    range_neg = int(range(0, dist_max, -1))# This is the range for the maximum distance
    # between words in the negative (-) direction
    pair_list.append('({} {})'.format(list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[range_pos]))
    pair_list.append('({} {})'.format(list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[range_neg]))
```

It's not much, but basically, I want to make a list to put all the pairs in, which will make the length part easier, and I need to make sure I don't add anything if the maximum distance is out of the list range. Any tips are appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: There's an additional detail here that you haven't shared, isn't there?  The words in each pair have to be in alphabetical order.  Otherwise, `whistle vest` would be the last entry.

Comment: Wait I did, above my code. Sorry if it's all over the place.

Comment: You're right.  I read that incorrectly.  My apologies.

Comment: My apologies, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructs the whole list of pairs.  Note that I use a `set` to eliminate the duplicates.

```
pairs = set()
for i in range(len(list_for_pairs)):
    for j in range(-dist_max,dist_max+1):
        if not j:
            continue
        if 0 <= i+j < len(list_for_pairs):
            w1, w2 = list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[i+j]
            if w1 > w2:
                w2,w1 = w1,w2
            pairs.add( (w1,w2) )
pairs = sorted(list(pairs))
#print(pairs)
print(len(pairs), "distinct pairs")
for i in range(5):
    print( pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1])
print("...")
for i in range(-5,0):
    print( pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1])
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py  
Enter the maximum distance between words ==> 2
54 distinct pairs   
apples bakery       
apples basket       
apples bike         
apples truck        
bakery basket       
...                 
puppy weather       
safety vest         
scratch trash       
track truck         
vest whistle        
                    
C:\tmp>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of the set, I was struggling so much with the duplicates. The code is easy to understand, thank you Mr. Roberts!

Comment: If you do the iteration deterministically, this is overkill.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pair_list = []
for i in range(len(list_for_pairs)):
   if i > 0:
        for j in range(max(0, i - 2)):
             pair_list.append('({} {})'.format(list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[j]))
   if i < len(list_for_pairs) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, min(len(list_for_pairs), i + 2)):
             pair_list.append('({} {})'.format(list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[range_neg]))
```

For each i, j goes from 1. i - 2 to i - 1 and 2. i + 1 to i + 2, if exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a nested for loop that is an offset from the current index plus and minus dist_max. Then just make sure the offset isn't 0 and would be in bounds.

```py
pair_list = []
for i, word in enumerate(list_for_pairs):
    for offset in range(-dist_max, dist_max+1):
        if offset and 0 <= i + offset < len(list_for_pairs): # Ignore when offset is 0 or would be out of bounds
            otherword = list_for_pairs[i + offset]
            pair_list.append((word, otherword))

print(pair_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to search before and behind, since the pairs are added alphabetically irrespective of order. In your list, replicated below, notice that there is no need to analyze `'weather + challenge'` and `'challenge + weather'` twice.

```
list_for_pairs = ['weather', 'puppy', 'challenge', 'house', 'whistle', \
                  'nation', 'vest', 'safety', 'house', 'puppy', 'card', \
                  'weather', 'card', 'bike', 'equality', 'justice', 'pride', \
                  'orange', 'track', 'truck', 'basket', 'bakery', 'apples', 'bike', \
                  'truck', 'horse', 'house', 'scratch', 'matter', 'trash']
dist_max = 2
```

If your list does not contain duplicates, you don't need a set to avoid duplication. All you need to do is not to add the duplicates! A simple implementation would look like this:

```
pairs = []
for i in range(dist_max, len(list_for_pairs)):
    for j in range(i - dist_max, i):
        pair = list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[j]
        if pair[1] < pair[0]:
            pair = pair[::-1]
        pairs.append(pair)
pairs.sort()
```

This is well suited for a list comprehension, especially if you use `sorted` instead of manually swapping the pair:

```
pairs = sorted(sorted([list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[j]]) 
         for i in range(dist_max, len(list_for_pairs)) for j in range(i - dist_max, i))
```

You can replace `[list_for_pairs[i], list_for_pairs[j]]`, with `list_for_pairs[j:i+1:i-j]`. In my opinion it looks prettier, though I'm not sure there's any other advantage to doing that:

```
pairs = sorted(sorted(list_for_pairs[j:i+1:i-j]) for i in range(dist_max, len(list_for_pairs)) for j in range(i - dist_max, i))
```

Since in practice your list *does* contain duplicates, you can use a `set` to aggregate the result. Since sets are unordered, can sort it after-the fact:

```
pairs = sorted(set(sorted(list_for_pairs[j:i+1:i-j])
               for i in range(dist_max, len(list_for_pairs)) for j in range(i - dist_max, i)))
```

As a fun corrolary, you can also use `itertools.groupby` to remove duplicates once the list has been sorted:

```
pairs = sorted(sorted(list_for_pairs[j:i+1:i-j])
               for i in range(dist_max, len(list_for_pairs)) for j in range(i - dist_max, i))
pairs = [k for k, g in groupby(pairs)]
```

Notice that you can write that last one as a one-liner too, but I think it's too long to be easily legible.

Comment: I see your point that we don't need to search both forward and back, but because the list contains duplicates, you still have a problem.  You'll get `puppy / weather` and `house / puppy` from two places.

Comment: @TimRoberts. Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed the duplicates. Updated now.